# Is onetoughnerd.me protected by the 1st Amendment?

Tags: united-states, liability

I saw [a website](http://onetoughnerd.me) that appears to be making fun of Rick Snyder, and specifically his handling of the Flint Water Crisis and his Twitter handle. As the following log shows, it redirects to a URL shortener link with the word Flint Water, and takes the reader to an image of a glass getting filled with water.

[image: a website]

I don't know who did it, but it showed up on a blog post as a newly registered site.  Is this a satire website that is protected under the 1st Amendment?

Comment: Devin Nunes Cow is a twitter account that has won a declaratory judgment that is parody and criticism.

Comment: See https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6795/legal-issues-of-a-website-such-as-businessnamesucks-com

Answer (score 5):

Of course it is protected by the first amendment.  Everyone in the US is protected by the first amendment.

It's possible that some statements published on the site might fall afoul of any of the well established exceptions to first amendment protection, but in general the site is protected.